# Topological Structure on Tangent Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am learning differential manifold and reading the book *Introduction to Smooth Manifold* written by Lee. I am stuck at the definition of tangent bundle. Book says

> $TM$ has a natural topology.

My question is

> what is a natural topology?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know what "a natural topology" means in general, or do you want to understand precisely what the topology on $TM$ is? Here I don't think "natural" has some mathematical meaning, it's just the author's way of saying that it's not some crazy, weird topology that you wouldn't expect.

Comment: Maybe without dilatation or bending.

Comment: In the proposition you're looking at, I was using the word "natural" informally, just to mean that the topology and smooth structure on $TM$ are completely determined by the topology and smooth structure on $M$, without any arbitrary choices. But there are ways of making this more rigorous. See, for example, Proposition 10.24 and Problem 11-18 in the same book.

Comment: @Narasimham I want to know the topology on $TM$.

Comment: It is clearing the decks for a smooth sailing ahead as precursor to what is going to be presented more importantly without wild diffeo-morphisms rather than  what the TM topology per se, is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask such a question I think you should mention that the statement you are referring to is a claim in a proposition of said book.

If you read the proof of that proposition you will see how the author defines (in a more or less straightforward way, which probably led to call it natural) a manifold structure and with this, a topology on $TM$, which is induced by $M$ and the projection map.